Using patch-package for react-native-paper does nothing?
I am developing a smartphone app using React Native Expo and adjusted the source code of a DataTable component so that I can have text wrapping per row of data. When I make changes to the source code and use patch-package, the content of the page doesn't change, even though all signs suggest it should. I tried first forking the repo but from what I've read its structure is actually different from the one hosted on npm so I was running into babel issues and turned to this for an "easy fix." Am I a failure who should quit this field? According to the documentation, it should be simple so I'm extra discouraged.
My steps:

Make desired changes to .../Native/node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/DataTable/DataTableCell.tsx

Add the following to the package.json scripts:
"postinstall": "patch-package"

Run npx patch-package react-native-paper

Terminal output:
• Creating temporary folder

• Installing react-native-paper@5.12.3 with npm

• Diffing your files with clean files

✔ Created file patches/react-native-paper+5.12.3.patch




Run npm i

Terminal output:
> <app-name>@1.0.0 postinstall

> patch-package

patch-package 8.0.0

Applying patches...

react-native-paper@5.12.3 ✔




.../Native/patches/react-native-paper+5.12.3.patch contents suggests the changes took
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/DataTable/DataTableCell.tsx b/node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/DataTable/DataTableCell.tsx
index 8601e50..4d21c23 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/DataTable/DataTableCell.tsx
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/DataTable/DataTableCell.tsx
@@ -84,7 +84,7 @@ const DataTableCell = ({
         testID={testID}
         maxFontSizeMultiplier={maxFontSizeMultiplier}
       >
-        {children}
+        MELONS!
       </CellContent>
     </TouchableRipple>
   );
@@ -106,11 +106,11 @@ const CellContent = ({
   return (
     <Text
       style={textStyle}
-      numberOfLines={1}
+      numberOfLines={3}
       maxFontSizeMultiplier={maxFontSizeMultiplier}
       testID={`${testID}-text-container`}
     >
-      {children}
+      MELONS!
     </Text>
   );
 };




Yet I see no melons on my page! I just see the {children} that I have written in there presently. If I delete them, still nothing. I've reloaded the app, cleared the cache, etc. Also when I delete node_modules and reinstall them, the melons goes away in the source code for react-native-paper, but remains in the patches directory. This is fine right? As far as I understand that output is upstream and "found first" so it is used instead of the corresponding part in the source file?
How to use patch-package to patch TSX files I've looked at this and have tried to make changes to .../Native/node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/components/DataTable/DataTableCell.js but still nothing...
